# How can I check active connection in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle-sqldeveloper, c3p0

We have used connection pooling using hibernate, we want to track active connections in the pool. Is it possible to find out using query OR any DB tool?

Comment: What is your definition of active connection? You can be connected to Oracle, but have no sessions. You can be connected, have session, but it would be an idle session(no active transactions). You can be connected, have session and a transaction can be in progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can monitor c3p0 by JMX, or write your own code to do so via the [PooledDataSource](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/PooledDataSource.html) interface.

The property you want to observe is `numBusyConnectionsAllUsers` or `numBusyConnectionsDefaultUser` (whether via JMX or direct access to `PooledDataSource`. These two values will be the same in the most usual case where you only access Connections via the authetication information configured in your DataSource. If you do use multiple authentications, then the two values will be different (and you might be interested in the method `getNumBusyConnections(username, password)`.

JMX monitoring is fun and easy!

Answer (score 5):

you can query the `v$session`

```
select * from v$session where USERNAME='<username configured in c3p0>'
```

You can find more about v$session columns [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_3016.htm), the view has an active column indicating if some sql is executing.

You need some explicit privileges to issue query against v$session something like

```
GRANT SELECT ON v_$session TO <user who monitor>;
```