# ORA-12571: TNS:packet writer failure

Tags: oracle

I was running a job from task scheduler. I'm getting this `ORA-12571:TNS:packet writer failure`.
`tnsnames.ora` file was also present in the job path. This error occuring when it tries to open a connection to Oracle DB.
Is this may be because of all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached?

It would be great if anyone could share their resolutions, Thanks!

Reason and resolution for the ORA error.

Comment: You can try turning on sqlnet tracing to see if there's more detail captured, but if the error persists you will need to contact Oracle Support. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/error-help/db/ora-12571/ Has this *ever* worked and established a successful connection? Is there a firewall or network ACL in the connection path that could be preventing the connection? I've seen some firewalls what would allow an initial connect or tnsping (unencrypted) and then break the connection when traffic encryption kicked in and it couldn't recognize the protocol anymore.

Comment: you should check if there are alreaydy too many connctions to the server https://stackoverflow.com/a/30399712/5193536  if this is a test server restart the server